# Prove that $\left(A\cap B\cap C\right)\cup\left(A^{C}\cup B^{C}\cup C^{C}\right)=U$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that $\left(A\cap B\cap C\right)\cup\left(A^{C}\cup B^{C}\cup C^{C}\right)=U$

Since it is an equality be must prove that
$$\left(A\cap B\cap C\right)\cup\left(A^{C}\cup B^{C}\cup C^{C}\right)\subseteq U$$
$$U\subseteq\left(A\cap B\cap C\right)\cup\left(A^{C}\cup B^{C}\cup C^{C}\right)$$

Comment: You are correct that the general method to show “set equality” is what you mentioned. However, the first part is trivial. Any set is by definition a subset of the global set. Have you tried to do the second part?

Answer (score 1):

Use De Morgan's Law $S^C\cup T^C=(S\cap T)^C$ twice to get
$$A^C\cup B^C\cup C^C=(A\cap B\cap C)^C.$$
Then clearly the union of $A\cap B\cap C$ with its complement will give the whole universe.

Answer (score 0):

I like to consider elements of the sets in question.

Let $x \in U$. One case is that $x\in A \cap B\cap C$. If this is not true, then $x \in D^C$ for at least one of $D = A, B, C$ . Then, $x\in A^C\cup B^C\cup C^C$. Now, we have proven the second statement.